# improve this very-simple dictionary generator in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple dict generator. It works but it isn't very functional yet.

I'd like to improve it by being able to change the max size of the output without touching the code.

```
letr='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for i in range(len(letr)):
    t=letr[i]
    print t
    for t2 in letr:
        print t+t2
        for t3 in letr:
            print t+t2+t3
            for t4 in letr:
                print t+t2+t3+t4
                for t5 in letr:
                    print t+t2+t3+t4+t5
```

Comment: This would be a good question for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: btw, ´import string; string.lowercase´ so you dont have to type the alphabet again :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import itertools

def dict_gen(n):
    letr = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    return itertools.chain(''.join(j) for i in range(n) 
                           for j in itertools.product(letr, repeat=i+1))
```

Usage:

```
for word in dict_gen(n):  # replace n with the max word length you want
    print word
```

Unlike some of the other answers this will include duplicates like your example ('aa', 'bb', etc).

`dict_gen()` will return a generator, but you can always just pass it into `list()` if you need to access elements by index:

```
>>> words = list(dict_gen(5))
>>> len(words) == 26 + 26**2 + 26**3 + 26**4 + 26**5  # verify correct length
True
>>> words[20:30]  # transition from one letter to two letters
['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad']
>>> words[-10:]   # last 10 elements
['zzzzq', 'zzzzr', 'zzzzs', 'zzzzt', 'zzzzu', 'zzzzv', 'zzzzw', 'zzzzx', 'zzzzy', 'zzzzz']
```

Comment: Nice! All answers are good but yours is the fastest. `python dict.py | grep -i zzzzz` takes 9 seconds in my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

```
letr = ''.join(chr(o) for o in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1))
import itertools
print [''.join(word) for word in itertools.permutations(letr, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Itertools is your best friend.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> gen = ("".join(i) for i in itertools.permutations(letr, 5))
>>> list(gen)[-10:]
['zyxwm', 'zyxwn', 'zyxwo', 'zyxwp', 'zyxwq', 'zyxwr', 'zyxws', 'zyxwt', 'zyxwu', 'zyxwv']
```

If you want to get all the permuations, you could write a generator yourself:

```
import itertools

def perms(seq):
     for n in range(len(seq)+1):
         for i in itertools.permutations(seq, n):
             yield i
```

Check the Python documentation for itertools and generators for more info.

Comment: Note that his does permutations, not combinations.